# Size of an object without using sizeof in C++

Tags: c++

This was an interview question:

> Say there is a class having only an int member. You do not know how many bytes the int will occupy. And you cannot view the class implementation (say it's an API). But you can create an object of it. How would you find the size needed for int without using sizeof.

He wouldn't accept using `bitset`, either.

Can you please suggest the most efficient way to find this out?

Comment: Sounds more like a vague riddle than a proper interview question to me.

Comment: Make an array of the objects and compare the memory address of the first and of the second entry. May still not get the size of int, if the class or a superclass has virtual member functions / constructors.

Comment: Point out that sizeof is exactly the tool to do that job and that no professional code should try to implement it again. Then offer pseudo code `int array[2]; print &(a[1])-&(a[0]);`.

Comment: You dont necessarily need a proper array, simple point arithmetic can deduce the answer.

Comment: What a stupid interview question. If it was one of 100 - fine. If it was one of less than 10 - screw that interview.

Comment: I think the idea of the question is whether the candidate spots that the idea itself is unhelpful and only on the second order, whether the cadidate can come up with any method. Also I consider the whole class thing is a decoy, because the actual question is about size of int, not size of class containing int. The difference might be target of the question, too.

Comment: Could also be about the candidates ability to clarify incomplete, misleading, unnecesserarily restrictive, requirements by starting a suitable communication with the customer. I.e. this question is not about C, it is about being a professional being able to look beyond the programming.

Comment: _@CuriousKrish_ [Run, run, run away](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnBlst3T7bY). You won't like to work for a company that asks such interview questions.

Comment: @Jesper I would have immediately left at that point, and wished them good luck for their further business.

Comment: Would `const auto int_size = (char*)((int*)(nullptr) + 1) - (char*)nullptr;` be defined behavior? I feel it would violate some rule, but I'm not sure which.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Arithmetic on a null pointer is undefined.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ because I got the invite on my phone and never really figured out how to join/participate yet.

Comment: @jesper I've invited you again.

Comment: @Yunnosch developers, especially junior should not directly communicate to the customer, especially one that gives misleading, unnecessary restrictive requirements.

Comment: @Slava That is true. But when you interview, you want to know whether they know to ask, which is different from letting them do it to your money cows. But you are right, I should have said "customer contact responsible"  or "requirement manager", instead of "customer".

Comment: @Yunnosch maybe then their questions should be more straightforward "do you really want to work in a company, where PM are idiots?" or "have you prepared to be inside "office space" movie?" - you know, those people are juniors, they may not understand such indirect tip like question above.

Comment: @slava I *so* agree.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your responses. The interviewer was leading me to think on lines of overflow and underflow. I did finally suggest the pointer arithmetic solution which he half heatedly agreed on. I just wanted to reaffirm if my line of thinking was correct.

Answer (score 4):

The following program demonstrates a valid technique to compute the size of an object.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
   int f;
};

int main()
{
   // Create an object of the class.
   Foo foo;

   // Create a pointer to it.
   Foo* p1 = &foo;

   // Create another pointer, offset by 1 object from p1
   // It is legal to compute (p1+1) but it is not legal
   // to dereference (p1+1)
   Foo* p2 = p1+1;

   // Cast both pointers to char*.
   char* cp1 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(p1);
   char* cp2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(p2);

   // Compute the size of the object.
   size_t size = (cp2-cp1);

   std::cout << "Size of Foo: " << size << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that requirement to avoid `sizeof()` coud be considered "valid"

Comment: @Slava, I think that's fair game for homework and interview questions.

Comment: I wonder if they would ask "how will you write a text on a piece of paper in case pen or pencil is prohibited to use?" on secretary interview.

Comment: I bet using `offsetof` whould be more "efficient" as does not require any memory allocation.

Comment: @Slava, `offsetof` computes the offset of a member from the start of a `struct`. I am not sure how that will work for what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @Slava: `offsetof` also counts padding, right? Can you provide a solution based on `offsetof`which does not depend on compiler/platform-specific padding?

Comment: @R Sahu: I think that `p1+1` is valid due to the "points one after the last element of an array", right? But just to be picky: is a single object instance considered as an array, or is there any other reason why `p1+1` is guaranteed to be legal?

Comment: Create a structure with 2 ints and difference of offsets is == `sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Using pointer algebra:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    int a;
};

int main() {
    A a1;
    A * n1 = &a1;
    A * n2 = n1+1;
    std::cout << int((char *)n2 - (char *)n1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n1--` is undefined. You can only do pointer arithmetic with pointers belonging to the same array (or one-past-the-end).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, molbdnilo thanks, just declaring `A a1;` to don't invoke UB

Comment: @Galik, thanks for pointing it. I think it may depend on architecture/implementation, added `std::abs`...

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative without using pointers. You can use it if in the next interview they also forbid pointers. Your comment *"The interviewer was leading me to think on lines of overflow and underflow"* might also be pointing at this method or similar.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    unsigned int x = 0, numOfBits = 0;
    for(x--; x; x /= 2) numOfBits++;
    std::cout << "number of bits in an int is: " << numOfBits;
    return 0;
}
```

It gets the maximum value of an `unsigned int` (decrementing zero in unsigned mode) then subsequently divides by 2 until it reaches zero. To get the number of *bytes*, divide by `CHAR_BIT`.

Answer (score -1):

Pointer arithmetic can be used without actually creating any objects:

```
class c {
    int member;
};

c *ptr = 0;
++ptr;
int size = reinterpret_cast<int>(ptr);
```

Alternatively:

```
int size = reinterpret_cast<int>( static_cast<c*>(0) + 1 );
```